# Windows 7 is corrupt; How to save Windows settings on clean install

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, nas

Last week I had problems with my PC and I fixed all hardware related issues, but the result window doesnt start up anymore.

I want to reinstall Windows and delete everything I currently have on the hard drive since it contains lot of junk, and probably some viruses.

I can acces all my files using Ubuntu (USB stick) and I also have a 3TB NAS available (WD MYCLOUD).

**I have the following questions:**

- how to save Windows settings like mouse sensitivity?
- can i transfer all files currently on the hard drive to NAS assuming Windows contains viruses without damaging my NAS?

edit: I dont care about having viruses in the NAS as long as they dont damage the device. i wont copy programs back to fresh windows only documents, settings, videos etc. and it is faster to copy everything than to sort the usefull stuff.

Comment: See this...http://lifehacker.com/5983652/how-to-do-a-clean-install-of-windows-without-losing-your-files-settings-and-tweaks

Answer (score 0):

For malware/virus removal scroll to bottom of this Answer.

For settings use Windows Easy Transfer that is built into Windows 7

It can be found in the All Programs>Accessories>System Tools folder on the start menu.

[image]

I selected usb
[image]

Choose Old Computer
[image]

It scans all the accounts on the PC

[image]

Choose your Accounts using the tick boxes

[image]

Hit Next and choose what you wish to back up, I would only do settings as its really the only thing it does fairly well

[image]

Set a password or skip that and hit Save

[image]

.

.
[For Malware see this link](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit/157533#157533)

Comment: I cant start up windows it will crash at windows logo, so sadly this option wont work :(

Comment: Will it start in Safe Mode?

Comment: No it instantly reboots

Comment: I would work on getting windows to boot because that is the only way to save settings.